# How to perform IBAction before dismiss sheetViewController from same UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I am writing a Cocoa Mac app in Objective-C and using Storyboard for my UI.

I have a "Confirm" button in my sheetViewController.m which I want to perform some action (save some settings) as well as dismiss the sheetViewController at the same time. They both use the sheetViewController.m as outlets.

Unfortunately, with Storyboard, I can only pick one received action (IBAction) or dismissController.

I want to perform the IBAction FIRST, before dismissing the sheet. How can I accomplish this?

Happy to do this in code as well instead of Storyboard if necessary!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to reference Storyboard ID in code:

On MainViewController:

```
- (IBAction)didClickButton:(NSButton *)sender {
    SheetViewController *sheetViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"SheetViewController"];
    // Must match Storyboard ID
    [self presentViewControllerAsSheet:sheetViewController];
}
```

On SheetViewController:

```
- (IBAction)didClickButton:(NSButton *)button {
    // Do something
    [self dismissViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codes to dismiss controller in your IBAction.