# cocoa - How to display a NSSavePanel modal window in front of another modal view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing a macOS document-based application using cocoa. I want to make a behavior like the start-up of XCode, namely: in a window, begin a modal view whose controller is called `viewController` by `presentViewControllerAsSheet:`, and after click the 'Next' button, show NSSavePanel by running `[self saveDocument:self]`.

My code is:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]
[self.contentViewController presentViewControllerAsSheet:viewController;
//...some set ups about the NSButton on the view.
//And in the method to handle the Next Button being clicked:
[self saveDocument:self];
```

After I run the application, when I click the 'Next' Button, nothing happens.

Comment: this is very little for us to know why your next button doesn't work. Verify if your IBAction is wired and method gets called. Also check if actions in your child sheet work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886877/how-to-perform-ibaction-before-dismiss-sheetviewcontroller-from-same-uibutton

Comment: @MarekH I have checked that the prepareSavePanel method has been called, but the save panel just doesn't show up.

Comment: Present sheets after another, not on top of another. Is the document new (no `fileURL`)? Which object is `self`? Is "nothing happens" "does not save" or "does not display a save panel"?

Comment: @Willeke This document is new. self is a subclass of NSDocument. It is "does not display a save panel" (the prepareSavePanel is called)

Comment: Also try presentViewControllerAsModalWindow if it makes a change. Little experimenting might uncover the issue. Can you post minimum project (github) where you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Are you creating savePanel by yourself or you expect NSDocument to show it by calling saveDocument?. Confused what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with this problem myself. I was calling back from a secondary controller to my main document class with the data to be saved, and trying to call `save()` was not showing the modal dialog. Turns out I had to explicitly call back to the main thread to ensure the UI is shown:

```
newServerWindowController?.saveNewDocument = { remote in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let newDoc = self.document else { return }
        newDoc.remote = remote
        newDoc.save(self)
        self.windowController?.update()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!